# How to calculate mean absolute error for Bayesian modeling based on Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation with Brms package in R

Tags: r, prediction, bayesian, brms, leave-one-out

I am fitting a Bayesian model to predict a test score using the `Brms` package.
I would like to know how to calculate the 'Mean Absolute Error' based on 'Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation' (LOO) using the `LOO` package, but I could not find any information related to how to actualize it by myself.

I would really appreciate if somebody demonstrate me how to calculate MAE based on LOO.

Here is a replicable sample code:

```
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
n <- 100 # number of observations
predictor_1 <- rnorm(n)
predictor_2 <- rnorm(n)
test_score <- 5 + 2*predictor_1 + 3*predictor_2 + rnorm(n)
data <- data.frame(test_score, predictor_1, predictor_2)
head(data)

fit <- brm(test_score ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2, data = data)
predicted_test_score <- predict(fit)

# calculate mean absolute error
mae <- mean(abs(predicted_test_score - data$test_score))
mae
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `brms::kfold_predict()` can be used for this and there is an easily adaptable example in the help file, see `?brms::kfold_predict()`.

Perform LOOCV and *save the fits* (object size grows quickly with nobs!)

```r
fit_LOO <- kfold(fit, save_fits = TRUE, chains = 1, folds = "loo")
```

Obtain samples (1000 is the default) from the posterior predictive distribution of each of the 100 observations. This yields a 1000x100 matrix.

```r
predict_LOO <- kfold_predict(fit_LOO, method = "predict")
```

```
> dim(predict_LOO$yrep)
[1] 1000  100
```

Define and compute your desired loss (based on posterior means):

```r
MAE <- function(y, yrep) {
  yrep_mean <- colMeans(yrep)
  mean(abs(yrep_mean - y))
}
```

```
> MAE(y = predict_LOO$y, yrep = predict_LOO$yrep)
[1] 0.7846185
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to calculate the `MAE` based on `LOO` using the `loo` package, you need to fit the Bayesian model using the `brm` function from the `brms` package, then, perform Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation using the `loo` function. Also, you will need to extract the pointwise log-likelihood matrix from the `brmsfit` object and calculate the expected log pointwise predictive density (ELPD) differences using the `loo::loo_compare` function.Finally, you have to calculate the LOO mean absolute error.

```
if (!requireNamespace("brms", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("brms")
}
library(brms)
if (!requireNamespace("loo", quietly = TRUE)) {
install.packages("loo")
}
library(loo)
fit <- brm(test_score ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2, data = data, save_all_pars = TRUE)
loo_fit <- loo(fit, save_psis = TRUE)
log_lik <- log_lik(fit)
elpd_diff <- loo::loo_compare(loo_fit, loo_fit)
loo_mae <- mean(abs(exp(elpd_diff$diff)))
print(loo_mae)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Olutomiwa Adeliyi. I am not familiar with the usage of `loo_compare` in this manner. Can we put the same `brmsfit` object in `loo_compare`? Do you know any related documents or papers that used this approach?